# NO_PUBKEY error while upgrading from 12.04

Tags: 13.04

```
Fetched 72 B in 23s (3 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

Comment: You can not upgrade from or to (is that why it is tagged 13.04?) a version that is end of life. Create a backup of your personal files and reinstall. If you want to upgrade please stay within versions that are current (that would be 16.04 for LTS, and 17.04 for not-LTS)

Answer (score -1):

Try to remake the bootable usb and make sure its formated Fat32 not as NTFS.Oh and sometimes people download the iso from torrents and CNET where most of the  times they face problems as for example not valid keys incomplete packages ect.So make sure you download the iso from the official ubuntu page (which is the link below) and make sure u make the bootable usb the right way.Btw sometimes this could be caused by the software you have used to create the bootable usb,most of the people use Rufus and it works like a charm but you could even use something else like Win32 Disk Imager or UUI(Universal Usb Installer).I hope this helped

The official download page for the iso you need
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop